# sql oracle introduction after every command

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to command line sql. But after a lot of work i finally understodo how to log into the xampp server using:

```
mysql -u myusername -p mypassword mydbname;
```

This is using the shell in xampp.
But now that i want to run a few different commands, (`source` was in my mind), im having trouble because after every command nothing happens except the introductory paragraph of oracle mysql.

Please help. I want to add a table to my database using a .sql file. This doesnt happen in phpmyadmin because the file size is too big.

Comment: The oracle tag refers to the Oracle RDBMS. It's best not to use it on a MySQL question, even though the company called Oracle acquired MySQL when they acquired sun micro.

Comment: Since they use oracle in the decription, i figured this only happens in oracle's sql. So maybe this is a popular concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
mysql -u myusername -p mypassword mydbname <mysqlfile.sql;
```

This will pipe the commands in your SQL file to the mysql shell.

Comment: Doesn't work. As I said, any command results in the introductory paragraph.

Comment: @InVaDeR Sorry can't get you.

Comment: I can't add pics... I need some reputation. Could you give me your email address please?